# MySql - Joining 2 Tables where 2nd table is joined twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

I have a 2 tables (studentclass and user)

table studentclass

```
columns (id, class_name, user_schoolid_faculty, user_schoolid_student)
```

table user

```
columns (id, firstname, lastname, schoolid, position)

user_schoolid_faculty is a foreign key from schoolid

user_schoolid_student is a foreign key from schoolid
```

my 1st query is

```
 SELECT * FROM studentclass WHERE class_name = '$class_name'
```

I want to view the data of the user's firstname and lastname using the schoolid

```
 SELECT studentclass.class_name, user.firstname, user.lastname
 FROM studentclass
 INNER JOIN user
 ON studentclass.user_schoolid_faculty = user.schoolid
 WHERE user.position = 'Faculty'
 LEFT JOIN user
 ON studentclass.user_schoolid_student = user.schoolid
 WHERE user.position = 'Student'
```

It throws me error, not unique table/alias 'user'

Comment: Why dont you use aliasses? Aliasses reduces the query complication.

Comment: SELECT a.class_name, b.firstname, b.lastname
 FROM studentclass as a
 INNER JOIN [user] as b
 ON b.user_schoolid_faculty = a.schoolid
 WHERE a.position = 'Faculty'
 LEFT JOIN user
 ON b.user_schoolid_student = a.schoolid
 WHERE a.position = 'Student'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server use square bracket for the reserve keyword `user`.
Also add alias name for the tables.

```
SELECT SC.class_name, U1.firstname, U2.lastname
FROM studentclass SC
INNER JOIN [user] U1 ON SC.user_schoolid_faculty = U1.schoolid
LEFT JOIN [user] U2  ON SC.user_schoolid_student = U2.schoolid AND U2.position = 'Student'
WHERE U1.position = 'Faculty'
```

For MySQL:

```
SELECT SC.class_name, U1.firstname, U2.lastname
FROM studentclass SC
INNER JOIN `user` U1 ON SC.user_schoolid_faculty = U1.schoolid
LEFT JOIN `user` U2  ON SC.user_schoolid_student = U2.schoolid AND U2.position = 'Student'
WHERE U1.position = 'Faculty'
```

Comment: Thanks! =) I used this SELECT SC.class_name, U1.firstname, U1.lastname, U2.firstname, U2.lastname
FROM studentclass SC
INNER JOIN `user` U1 
ON SC.user_schoolid_faculty = U1.schoolid
LEFT JOIN `user` U2  
ON SC.user_schoolid_student = U2.schoolid 
AND U2.position = 'Student'
WHERE U1.position = 'Faculty'

Comment: it nailed what i needed =)

Answer (score 1):

For same table `user`, you should use different alias, and when you use `JOIN`, you should use `ON` to combine two tables, not `WHERE`, try this;)

```
SELECT studentclass.class_name, user1.firstname, user2.lastname
FROM studentclass
INNER JOIN user user1
ON studentclass.user_schoolid_faculty = user1.schoolid
AND user1.position = 'Faculty'
LEFT JOIN user user2
ON studentclass.user_schoolid_student = user2.schoolid
AND user2.position = 'Student'
```

And one unclear point, why do you use one `INNER JOIN` and one `LEFT JOIN` in this query?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use aliasses for your tables:

```
SELECT studentclass.class_name, u1.firstname, u1.lastname
FROM studentclass
 INNER JOIN user u1
 ON studentclass.user_schoolid_faculty = u1.schoolid
 WHERE user.position = 'Faculty'
 LEFT JOIN user u2
 ON studentclass.user_schoolid_student = u2.schoolid
 WHERE u1.position = 'Student'
```